# I want to save and load the Area description in Google Tango kit

Tags: google-project-tango

So I build Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/Scenes/AreaLearning. But, when the _PopulateList function calls, the error is caused.
**E/tango: file_io.cc:539 Error(13) opening path: /data/data/com.google.tango/files/Tango/ADFs/ failed with error Permission denied.**

And when the saveCurrent() functions calls, the error is caused. 
**E/tango: file_io.cc:773 Couldn't prepare directory /data/data/com.google.tango/files/Tango/ADFs/ - -1**

I think this app has not permission at /data/data/com.google.tango/*.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very similar to mine.

For my case,

Settings > Apps > Tango Core -> disable and clear data

then

app store > search tango core > enable

This makes my tablet save-able